# Divs won't fit within container

Tags: css, sharepoint, html

I'm trying to create a layout with a sidebar along the left and 3 divs stacked on top of each other. However, I'm having through getting my divs to fit within the container. I'm also having issues getting the container to fit the width of the page without forcing horizontal scroll

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is what it looks like on my site:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/rwq3d/

Comment: It's because everything is absolutely positioned.

Comment: How should I position it?

Comment: If you need to you should do `relative` on the parent and `absolute` for the children inside.

Comment: when I change the parent to relative, it collapses and changing the top/middle/bottom divs causes them to stop on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood you correctly, your problem is that padding actually increases the size of the boxes. That means if you give a box 100% width and add 1% padding, you'll end up with 102% box width (1% left and 1% right). The solution in that case would be to simply reduce the box width to 98%, but with fixed size padding, this isn't so easy.

Still, there is a solution to this: the `box-sizing` attribute.

With this code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Updated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwq3d/1/

Comment: That fixed the issue I was having where the boxes where causing an horizontal scroll. But I'm still having an issue with the divs extending past the container

Comment: That is because once you use `position:absolute` on any element, it becomes a block element and is completely taken out of the "flow" of the content. It is in a layer seperate from the normal content and thus the parent element of the absolutely positioned element doesn't know the size of it's child anymore. If you want to stick with absolute positioning, you will have to use JavaScript to adjust the heights or use the css `float` with a clearfix (lots of info on google) to achieve your layout.

Comment: I don't need to stick with absolute, i just used it cause that's what worked at the time. Someone commented saying I should use relative and absolute for the child divs but even that is giving me trouble. The container div when relative just collapses.

Comment: You should really read up on the `float` property of CSS. What you want to do can definitely be achieved with that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `display: inline-block;` 
I'm not sure if this is helpful but this is the way i'd do it:

This is a part of the HTML:

```
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <section id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li id="menuHome"> <a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a>

                </li>
                <li id="menuUsers"> <a href='#'><span>Users</span></a>

                </li>
                <li id="menuGroups"> <a href='#'><span>Groups</span></a>

                </li>
                <li id="menuSites"> <a href='#'><span>Sites</span></a>

                </li>
                <li id="menuReports"><a href='#'>
                   <span>Reports</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="content">
            <div id="top">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tempor nec risus non ullamcorper. Donec porttitor, elit in adipiscing condimentum, neque lectus tristique augue, a euismod metus diam gravida augue. Etiam neque nulla, dapibus a odio semper, tempus volutpat nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut scelerisque nulla vel turpis luctus, sed euismod quam sodales. Mauris sem leo, tincidunt fermentum felis a, sollicitudin commodo justo. Nulla suscipit facilisis dui, eu viverra odio porttitor vel. Integer iaculis sapien posuere, accumsan lectus ac, euismod risus. Nam in mattis sapien. Sed elementum bibendum condimentum. Vestibulum ac lectus id augue vulputate sollicitudin vel quis purus.</div>
            <hr>
            <div id="middle">Aenean elit ligula, luctus id leo auctor, egestas interdum velit. Praesent sit amet consectetur eros, ut adipiscing eros. Praesent convallis arcu a elementum lobortis. Vestibulum magna ante, imperdiet eget porta eu, interdum vel lorem. Morbi mattis quis dui sed porta. Maecenas varius ac augue a viverra. Nunc velit ipsum, mattis facilisis bibendum ac, venenatis vitae odio. Fusce sed interdum ligula, et consequat lorem.</div>
            <hr>
            <div id="bottom">Aliquam rhoncus purus ac lorem suscipit accumsan. Pellentesque elementum volutpat risus, et consequat lectus pulvinar sed. Nullam posuere at metus vel lobortis. Ut facilisis a velit gravida aliquam. Nam aliquet iaculis vulputate. Vestibulum nec eros cursus, dignissim nulla ut, semper tellus. Curabitur ac ultrices sapien. Donec diam sapien, congue ut libero vitae, mollis adipiscing neque. Quisque interdum, eros vitae tempor elementum, quam lacus dapibus erat, at porttitor nisl nunc in massa. Nam ut nulla orci. Etiam vitae accumsan orci. Phasellus libero dui, tincidunt mollis feugiat ac, fermentum sed nulla. Sed lorem turpis, consequat vitae nibh eget, adipiscing placerat arcu. Phasellus libero mi, eleifend eget nulla eget, accumsan imperdiet dui. Morbi pretium dictum est in posuere.</div>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

And for the CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 98%;/*A little smaller than the page no no problems arise*/
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
#sidebar {
    vertical-align: top;/*We align the element with the top of the 
    elements adjacent to it.*/
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;/*Inline block makes block elements act as if they were inline. It is very useful for these kind of case. And later on if t}you want the page to be responsive*/
    width: 20%;/*You have to set a width for the element*/
    margin-right : 5px;
}
/*The properties for content are similar to those of the sidebar*/
#content {
    width: 75%;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*You don{t really have to make changes in the elements of the content, since they behave as a block should, they sstack one below the other.*/
#top, #middle, #bottom {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

I'm not very sure if this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.